# why is lift framework so slow?

Tags: performance, scala, lift

I am learning Lift framework. I used project template from git://github.com/lift/lift_25_sbt.git and started server with *container:start* sbt command.

This template application displays just simple menu. If i use **ab** from apache to measure performance, its pretty bad. I am missing something fundamental to improve performance?

```
C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\httpd-2.0.64\Apache2\bin>ab -n 30 -c
 10 http://127.0.0.1:8080/
Benchmarking 127.0.0.1 (be patient).....done

Server Software:        Jetty(8.1.7.v20120910)
Server Hostname:        127.0.0.1
Server Port:            8080

Document Path:          /
Document Length:        2877 bytes

Concurrency Level:      10
Time taken for tests:   8.15625 seconds
Complete requests:      30
Failed requests:        0
Write errors:           0
Total transferred:      96275 bytes
HTML transferred:       86310 bytes
Requests per second:    3.74 [#/sec] (mean)
Time per request:       2671.875 [ms] (mean)
Time per request:       267.188 [ms] (mean, across all concurrent requests)
Transfer rate:          11.73 [Kbytes/sec] received
```

Comment: I'm surprised by this, as I've found Lift to be pretty quick. A thought: I notice a several-second-long delay on the first request I make to the server after starting it up. Perhaps your benchmark is seeing that delay and it is throwing off the results? Maybe you will get quicker results if you let it "warm up" first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you running it in production mode? I found i had like 30 rps in devel, but over 250 in production mode. ( **https://www.assembla.com/spaces/liftweb/wiki/Run_Modes** )

Comment: Yes, that's what i was thinking. Or your hardware is like 10 years old. :s

Comment: In production mode I have 100 requests/sec.

Answer (score 1):

- as mentioned earlier, you should run Lift in production mode. This is the main key to get good performance. All templates are cached this way, and other optimizations apply.
- if you want to measure something not abstract and theoretical, then you should give the JVM time to "warm up", apply it's JIT optimizations. So, you should apply ~thousand requests first and totally ignore them (must be a couple of seconds). After that, measure the real performance of an already-started server
- there are some slight JVM optimizations, altrough they seem more like a hack to me, and give a boost not more than around 20%
- other small hacks include serving static content with nginx, starting the application in a dedicated server instead of Simple Build Tool and such.

Comment: ey @vasya-novikov what could be those JVM optimizations you talk about?

Comment: @tyoc213, I failed to net-search the exact option, but it's about the percentage of newly created objects that should be tried to be garbage-collected. Means how often the JVM tries to garbage-collect, AFAIremember. This refers to general "JVM tuning", which might be a complex topic if it's really needed. For example, if you have a lot of machines and getting a 20% boost for your exact app really means something.

Comment: @tyoc213 (I never use the third thing, don't have time for this. The 4-th and 1-st work great, and 2-nd is just the way how JVM works.)

Comment: About JVM optimizations. Something like this usually gives some performance boost (but values depend on the application) `-XX:+UseParNewGC`, `-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC`, `-XX:SurvivorRatio=..`, `-Xmx..`  I don't like such things anyway.